# Брать информацию из .yml при помощи асинхронных запросов

Tags: javascript, jquery, jekyll

Есть такого рода инфа в папке `_data` проекта:

```
- name: Sketch 1
  src: /artworks/sketches/517.jpg

- name: Sketch 2
  src: /artworks/sketches/687.jpg
```

В нем перечислены названия и src к картинкам. Нужно вывести эти картинки после формирования всей страницы, то есть через JS и запросы к серверу. Файл этот может дополняться со временем, так что будет организован цикл, который просто берет src из этого файла и вставляет в контейнеры, например. 
Так вот вопрос: можно ли такое вообще сделать?
Вообще идея такая: Jekyll формирует страницу, используя такого рода файлы, выводит картинок 20 (с этим проблем нет, сделал). Далее как скролл достигает конца, делается запрос, достается ещё штук 20 src картинок, загружаются, и так далее пока не кончатся перечисления в этом файле.
Можно, конечно, именовать все картинки 1, 2, 3... и так далее, тогда легко их регистрировать и выводить по порядку, но не хочется этим заниматься, хочется закинуть, указать всю инфу в _data файле `.yml` и не париться.
Да и уточнение одно - используются github pages для публикации. Пхп не катит.
Есть какие-нибудь идеи? :D

Comment: Можно конечно, если ajax будет знать, где взять фаш файл с данными. Я бы посоветовал для данных хранить их в json файле т.к. тогда и парсить ничего не нужно будет (Насколько я понял jekyll не мешает этому.). Так вот вопрос - у вас будет открыт файл с данными по урл типа yoursite.com/data.json ? Если да, то решение простое и infinity scroll решений много.

Comment: Да, этот файл будет лежать в открытом репозетории вместе с сайтом.
С json не знаком совсем, но слышал про это расширение много... Используются github pages, он сам jekyll компилирует. Насчет скриптов и скролла вопрос не стоит (уже считай сделано), это так, чтобы задумку понять.  Можете, пожалуйста, подробнее рассказать об этом? Где и как брать, что парсить (если нужно - и как?), где узнать об этом всем?

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, считывает дату из файла yml из деректории _data.
создает массив из src

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/_data/sources.yml');
client.onload = (function(){

var txt = client.responseText;

var myRe = new RegExp("(\/.*?jpg)", "g");

var i = 0;
var arr = [];
try
{
   while(val = myRe.exec(txt)[0])
   {
    arr[i] = val;
    i++;
   }
}
catch(e)
{

}
console.log(arr);
})
client.send(null);
</script>
```

Comment: ответ помог??..

Comment: Я пока не могу сказать, честно говоря я его задал с опережением в несколько дней :D Он у меня висит в закрепленных закладках, как опробую такой способ и разберусь, что он делает и делает ли он то, то  поставлю галочку, не забуду.

Answer (score 0):

```
// пример json объекта внутри файла data.json
```

Formatted JSON Data

```
[
   {
      "name":"Image1",
      "scr":"/data/image2.jpg"
   },
   {
      "name":"ImageSomeName",
      "src":"/data/imageSomneName3.jpg"
   }
]
```

В таком виде у нас получается :

1) Это массив (т.к. у нас квадратные скобки [] )

2) в массиве 2 элемента, идущих через запятую т.е. {},{}

3) В каждом элементе у нас есть 2 поля - name и src.И у них есть значения. И потому для получения доступа к какому либо из полей конкретного элемента мы просто будет оперировать им вот так - `obj[0].name` и `obj[1].src`.

ну и сосбтвенно как вытащить данные из файла json

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "yourdomain.com/data.json",
  dataType: "json"
}).success(function(data) {
    // тут будет уже наш json объект, которым можно будет распоряжаться
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(er) {
    // тут будет ошибка если 1) файл не найден 2) форматировани json не соблюдено
    console.log(er.statusText);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, хорошо объяснил для меня, чайника)
Правда я столкнулся с тем, что хранить фотки на гитхабе таим родом не получится, поэтому src будут другими. Но это уже другой вопрос и он уже задан, спасиб)

Comment: @VostokSisters Разумеется нельзя) А то вы превратите гитхаб в хранилище, за что он вам спасибо не скажет). Картинки можно хранить на любом облачном сервисе (гугл, яндекс).

Comment: А подскажите, могу ли я пользоваться гугл-диском для хранения и размещения их на сайте-галлерее? Не изменится ли url к картинке со временем, через год или 10 лет? Волнует вопрос долговечности такого.

Comment: @VostokSisters ну если завести свой ящик (платный разумеется), то сколько нужно, столько и будет храниться. Но я не считаю это проблемой т.к. даже открытого облака хватает (1-5 гига зависит от сервиса). Просто храните ссылку к этому сервису как переменную. Если вдруг что изменится - меняешь это переменную и все ок.

Comment: В гугле можно только добавить места к диску, и всё. И там 15 гигабайт (этого хватит, я думаю). А насчет того, что если что-то изменится, то это неприемлемо. Все src должны быть навсегда. Если изменятся все пути к папке, мне все пути переписывать? Все 5 тысяч? Норм?

Comment: @VostokSisters Зачем переписывать, поменяется только относительный путь т.е. корневая папка. А структура проекта не меняется - и потому не нужно их менять. Просто заводится переменная типа `var src = "somedomain.com/db/app/"`, а пути для картинок будут типа 'var imgSrc = src+"img/image2.png"'. Меняем переменную src - и все пути снова валидны. Как то так

Comment: Ты говоришь про хостинг, спустя время ты потерял предмет разговора. А разговор шел про хостинг изображений на гугл облаке. Там ,повторюсь, меняются url.